# Yii2 - How to loop inside dynamicform wbraganca using javascript

Tags: javascript, yii2

I'm using dynamicform wbraganca to perform purchasing order operation.
In dynamicform, i have item, qty, price and total. if someone edit the item or qty, it will perform calculate its total and sum of total for each row item. What i want to ask how to know the total rows in the dynamicform so i can loop to sum the total.
here is my code

```
<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-3">
    <?= $form->field($detail, "[{$i}]item_id")->widget(Select2::className(), [
        'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Item::find()->all(), 'id', 'name'),
        'language' => 'en',
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select a item ...', 'onchange' => 'getItemPrice($(this))'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true,                               
        ],
    ]);
    ?>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-2">
    <?= $form->field($detail, "[{$i}]qty")->widget(MaskedInput::className(),
        [
            'clientOptions' => [
                'alias' => 'numeric',
                'groupSeparator' => ',',
                'digits' => 0,
                'autoGroup' => true,
                'removeMaskOnSubmit' => true,
                'rightAlign' => false,                                  
            ],
            'options' => [
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'onchange' => 'calculateSubtotal($(this))',                     
            ]                               
        ]) ?>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-2">
    <?= $form->field($detail, "[{$i}]price")->widget(MaskedInput::className(),
        [
            'clientOptions' => [
                'alias' => 'numeric',
                'groupSeparator' => ',',
                'digits' => 0,
                'autoGroup' => true,
                'removeMaskOnSubmit' => true,
                'rightAlign' => false,                              
            ],
            'options' => [
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'onchange' => 'calculateSubtotal($(this))',                                 
            ]
        ]) ?>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-2">
    <?= $form->field($detail, "[{$i}]total")->widget(MaskedInput::className(),
        [
            'clientOptions' => [
                'alias' => 'numeric',
                'groupSeparator' => ',',
                'digits' => 0,
                'autoGroup' => true,
                'removeMaskOnSubmit' => true,
                'rightAlign' => false,
            ]
        ]) ?>
</div>
```

and my javascript like this

```
<?php
$script = <<< JS

jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterInsert", function(e, item) {
    jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper .add-item").each(function(index) {
        calculateTotal(index+1);
    });
});

jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterDelete", function() {
    jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper .remove-item").each(function(index) {                
        calculateTotal(index+1);
    });
});

function getItemPrice(item){
    var index  = item.attr("id").replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
    var item_id = $('#purchaseorderdetail-'+ index + "-item_id").val();
    $.get('../item/get-price', {id : item_id}, function(data){
        $('#purchaseorderdetail-' + index + '-price').val(data);
        $('#purchaseorderdetail-' + index + '-qty').val(1);
        $('#purchaseorderdetail-' + index + '-total').val(data);
        calculateTotal(Number(index)+1);
    });     
}

function calculateSubtotal(item){   
    var index  = item.attr("id").replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");   
    var qty = $('#purchaseorderdetail-' + index + '-qty').val();
    qty = qty == "" ? 0 : Number(qty.split(",").join(""));
    var price = $('#purchaseorderdetail-' + index + '-price').val();
    price = price == "" ? 0 : Number(price.split(",").join(""));
    $('#purchaseorderdetail-' + index + '-total').val(qty * price);     
    calculateTotal(Number(index)+1);
}

function calculateTotal(index){    
    var total = 0;    
    for(i=0; i< index; i++){        
        var subtotal = $('#purchaseorderdetail-' + i + '-total').val();        
        subtotal = subtotal == "" ? 0 : Number(subtotal.split(",").join(""));    
        total = total + subtotal;
    }
    $('#purchaseorder-total').val(total);
}

JS;
$this->registerJs($script, $this::POS_END);
?>
```

the problem when doing update, it cannot calculate all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thanks to *insaneSkull* who help me answer the question.
here is the solution to sum the grandtotal

```
jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterInsert", function(e, item) {
    calculateTotal();   
});

jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterDelete", function(e) {
    calculateTotal();    
});

function getItemPrice(item){
    var index  = item.attr("id").replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
    var item_id = $('#purchaseorderdetail-'+ index + "-item_id").val();
    $.get('../item/get-price', {id : item_id}, function(data){
        $('#purchaseorderdetail-' + index + '-price').val(data);
        $('#purchaseorderdetail-' + index + '-qty').val(1);
        $('#purchaseorderdetail-' + index + '-total').val(data);
        calculateTotal();
    });     
}

function calculateSubtotal(item){    
    var index  = item.attr("id").replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");   
    var qty = $('#purchaseorderdetail-' + index + '-qty').val();
    qty = qty == "" ? 0 : Number(qty.split(",").join(""));
    var price = $('#purchaseorderdetail-' + index + '-price').val();
    price = price == "" ? 0 : Number(price.split(",").join(""));
    $('#purchaseorderdetail-' + index + '-total').val(qty * price);
    calculateTotal();
}

function calculateTotal(){    
    var total = 0;        
    jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper .remove-item").each(function(index) {
        var subtotal = $('#purchaseorderdetail-' + index + '-total').val();
        if(typeof(subtotal) != 'undefined'){
            subtotal = subtotal == "" ? 0 : Number(subtotal.split(",").join(""));    
            total = total + subtotal;    
        }        
    });
    $('#purchaseorder-total').val(total);
}
```

many thanks to insaneSkull